# On iOS, is there a way to search ONLY subviews with a certain tag?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

Because right now, `viewWithTag` actually search for itself first, and then all subviews recursively down the whole subtree, for a view with that tag.

But what if I set the tags of the subviews to 100, 101, etc, and later on, look for tag 100, but the parent of this current view sets the current view's tag to 100?  Then `viewWithTag` will return the current view instead of any subview.

It is also strange that if the code is

```
[fooView viewWithTag: 123]
```

why would the code want to search the subtree including fooView itself?  It is like, the code doesn't know fooView good enough to want to search for it too.  Or put it another way, `fooView` is told to search itself... which is strange.  A view doesn't know itself?  (need to do a search to look for itself?)

So is there a way to search for subviews and grand-subviews only (without searching for self)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take advantage of the recursive nature of `-viewWithTag:`

```
- (UIView *)viewWithTagNotCountingSelf:(NSInteger)tag
{
    UIView *toReturn = nil;

    for (UIView *subView in self.subviews) {
        toReturn = [subView viewWithTag:tag];

        if (toReturn) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Edit: this will drill down farther than "grand-subviews": it will get any view within the hierarchy that is not self. Also this is to be implemented in a category on `UIView`.

Comment: I wonder why the default behavior of `viewWithTag` is not this to begin with...  and we need to do something complicated to achieve it

Comment: I don't know why. I don't usually like to use `-viewWithTag:` if I can avoid it but maybe heavy users of it can chime in on that subject. Anyways, adding this into a category should be an easy way to get exactly what you want.

Comment: For example, I might do this: in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I will dequeue a cell, and if exists, then simply look for the existing label or the several UIImageView I added previously, by using this tag, so as to change the text or image, instead of removing all of them and recreate new ones

Comment: Works great for me. Lets me tag a scroll view and its child image view with the same lookup tag. I can now call `return [scrollView viewWithTagNotCountingSelf:scrollView.tag];` inside `- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`. Great when working with a set of scroll views.

Answer (score 3):

let result = view.subviews.filter{$0.tag == tag}.first

Answer (score 2):

After [reviewing the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag:) for `-viewWithTag:` and running a few tests, it appears the answer to OP's question is - This behavior is already provided.

> Return Value
>
> The view in the receiver’s hierarchy whose tag property matches the
>   value in the tag parameter.
>
> Discussion
>
> This method searches the current view and all of its subviews for the
>   specified view.

I am concluding this to mean that 'view' is also a 'subview', thus limiting the scope of the search.

Answer (score 1):

For 1 level:

```
UIView *view;
for (int i = 0; i < viewToSearch.subviews.count; i++){
    UIView *subview = viewToSearch.subviews[i];
    if (subview.tag == tagToSeach){
        view = subview;
        break;
    }
}
```

To search a view hierarchy with multiple levels:

```
__block UIView *view;
BOOL (^__block searchViewForTag)(UIView *,NSInteger) = ^(UIView *aView, NSInteger tag){
    for (UIView *subview in aView.subviews){
        if (subview.tag == tag){
            view = subview;
            return YES;
        }
        if (searchViewForTag(subview,tag)) return YES;
    }
    return NO;
};
NSInteger tagToSearchFor = 1;
searchViewForTag(viewToSearch,tagToSearchFor);

//Do something with view
```

Comment: this one only search for 1 level down?

Comment: @動靜能量 yes, view.subviews returns subviews 1 level down

Comment: @動靜能量 This is recursive & excludes returning the target view in the search.

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrSameViewTag = [NSMutableArray array];
for(UIView *subview in [yourView subviews]) //your view to find subview
{
    if(subview.tag == 123) //specific tah here
    {
        [arrSameViewTag addObject:subview]; //view found add in array
    } 
}
NSlog(@"arrSameViewTag : %@",arrSameViewTag);
```

To find specific like UIButton or any UIElement then like this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrSameViewTag = [NSMutableArray array];
for(id *subview in [yourView subviews]) //your view to find subview
{
  if([subview isKindofClass[UIButton class]) //any UIElement of specific type here
  {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)subview; //same UIElement mentioned for checking it
    if(btn.tag == 123) //specific tah here
    {
        [arrSameViewTag addObject:subview]; //view found add in array
    } 
  }
}
NSlog(@"arrSameViewTag : %@",arrSameViewTag)
```

Comment: What a speed... in 8 month 4599 score great...:)