# Why does this UIImageView think it's a UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, viewwithtag

In a view controller in a storyboard I have a simple view which has a subview image with tag 0 and a subview label with tag 1.

I'm trying to get the image like this:

```
UIImageView *myImage = (UIImageView*)[myView viewWithTag:0];
```

But when I do this:

```
myImage.highlighted = YES;
```

I get this:

```
-[UIView setHighlighted:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

It is clearly a UIImageView in the storyboard. Why would this cast not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `[myView viewWithTag:0]` which is the tag number for the main view as well

### Solution:

- Give your `UIImageView` object a tag of, say, `100`
- Access it now as `(UIImageView*)[myView viewWithTag:100]`

Comment: This does fix it, but I don't understand why the 0 matters, since these are subviews.

Comment: It isn't looking only at subviews for the tag.

Comment: @soleil Every view has a default tag of 0. And `viewWithTag:` starts with the receiver. So if the view you call it on has a matching tag, it will be returned.

Comment: ok, but what is the purpose of starting with the receiver? I mean, why would they design the API that way?

Comment: @soleil : well... when you do `[abcView viewWithTag:idx]`, it returns a **reference** to a view in `abcView` whose tag is `idx`. If `abcView`'s tag is `idx` then it returns a reference to itself. If not and suppose multiple `subview`s have the same `idx` tag number then the topmost view in `abcView`s hierarchy (_whose tag is `idx`_) is returned. Now... why it starts with `abcView` itself is something that I've not thought about but it seems like an interesting question.

Comment: @soleil A better question is "why shouldn't it start with the receiver"? It makes more sense as long as you use proper tags.

Comment: @rmaddy because if I ask you for your child named "Steve", I don't expect you to give me yourself if your name happens to be Steve.

Comment: @soleil The method is named `viewWithTag:`, not `subviewWithTag:`.

Comment: @soleil : that analogy is a little presumptuous as the objective-c equivalent would be `[steve whoIs:@"steve"]` and well... you know compilers \*sigh\* ...still evolving. But anyways... when you do `[abcView viewWithTag:idx]`, you're sending the `abcView` object a message to return a view whose tag is `idx`. So, technically, `abcView` is not the `UIView` but the class **that** contains the `UIView` (***which**, as per my observations, is often named `view`*) **that** contains the `subview`s. (_I may be wrong on this but this is what's on the top of my head right now_)

Comment: I'm still not convinced. Under this logic [someView subviews] should return itself as part of the array.

Comment: @soleil : well, the [description for `-viewWithTag`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) states `This method searches the current view and all of its subviews for the specified view.` so. I guess... that's that. It's Apple's implementation of this method.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't understand why they did it that way. If I wanted the parent view, I could just ask for it, or check its tag.

Comment: @soleil : yeah, beats me. there may be some stupid reason.

Comment: @soleil : [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12225184/2857130) -- No reason provided but a manual workaround can be seen in the accepted answer which is basically a category method on `UIView` named `-viewWithTagNotCountingSelf:` (_but you can name it `-subviewWithTag:`_;)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Glad to know I'm not the only one who thinks this  is a weird method.